# Calling Method from Different Python File

Tags: python, django, methods

As I'm currently learning Django / Python, I've not really been using the concept of Classes, yet. As far as I'm aware the method isn't static.. it's just a standard definition.

So let's say I have this Package called `Example1` with a `views.py` that contains this method:

```
def adder(x,y):
  return x + y
```

Then I have an `Example2` which also has a `views.py` where I'd like to use this method `adder`.

How would I got about doing this?

EDIT: In Java it would be a simple instantiation then a `instantiation.Method()` or if it was static it would be `SomeClass.Method()` however I'm unsure how I should approach this in Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python has module level and class level methods. In this concept a "module" is a very special class that you get by using `import` instead of `Name()`. Try

```
from Example1.views import adder as otherAdder
```

to get access to the module level method. Now you can call `otherAdder()` and it will execute the code in the other module. Note that the method will be executed in the context of `Example1.views`, i.e. when it references things, it will look there.

Comment: Thank you for the insight into 'module' level and 'class' level methods. I shall have to look into this. Thanks again for the thorough answer.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
from Example2.views import adder as myadder
myadder(x,y)
```

If you are unsure, you can always start a python shell and then use the [dir](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir) command to look inside the contents of packages to see what can be used.

Edit: Updated from comments to use 'as'

**OR**

```
# use ...views as myviews if you need to avoid name conflict on views
from Example2 import views
views.adder(x,y)
```

Comment: This should work, but would overwrite a potential local adder ... _bravado was writing about ...

Comment: add: Or the local adder would overwrite the imported one of course ... (I would suggest from ... import adder as adder2)

Answer (score 3):

Normally you import "modules"

I would suggest:

```
from Example2 import views as views2

x = views2.adder(1, 2)
```

I hope, I got this right, since I did not use packages till now ;-)